# How to add all files from a folder in src_uri in a bitbake file

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am having a folder in which there are too many c files (Approx 200 c files)

Right now in the bitbake file of that folder I am adding files in                SRC_URI variable like this:

```
SRC_URI = "file://filename_1.c \
           file://filename_2.c \
                   .
                   .
                   .
           file://filename_n.c \
```

It is very difficult to add files like this in a SRC_URI variable of a bitbake since I am having too many c files. What can be the shortest way to include all the c files in a bitabake file. Or Is there any way to add the directory of the c files and  it will include all the c files present in that directory.

Please help

Answer (score 10):

You can use wildcards.

```
SRC_URI = "file://*.c"
```

Comment: file:// urls with globbing are no longer supported. The recommended replacement is to simply reference a directory.

Answer (score 9):

If all of the files are in the same folder, just include the folder.

```
SRC_URI += " file://folder/ "
```

All files in the folder will be added.

Comment: is this recursive? what if folder contains subfolders?

Answer (score 1):

Make a tar with all .c files, then mention the tar file name in SRC_URI.

```
SRC_URI = "file://test.tar.gz"
```